# Universal Image Loader Memory management

Tags: android, memory-management

I am working on a custom gallery and using the UIL library for Image loading. I have a little problem; after images load in the gallery and i scroll down, coming back up the pictures always reload. Is there any sort of memory management I can use to keep the already loaded pictures from the reloading in the gallery after scrolling away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading shouldn't be the issue, as long as the images aren't fully reloading from the network -- i.e. they're cached and reloading from memory/disk.  This is something that's been solved by many different libraries.  I would suggest looking into either [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) rather than rolling a custom solution.